# Using Redux instead of cookie and local storage

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, local-storage

Will Redux store be cleaned after reloading the browser?
And can i use redux instead of cookie to save user info and token?

Answer (score 1):

Redux is a state management library so,on refresh ,the redux store contains only the `initialstate` of the reducers.If you want to save tokens or authenticated user info then save it in localStorage.And also make sure,you un set the local storage after logging out of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux Persist or build a middleware that will save the store everytime an action is dispatched and then create a HOC that when the app is reloaded (a.k.a the page is refreshed), it'll check the local storage for the item and then restore it to the store before the app is loaded and then render the application.

Depending on the complexity and if you want to blacklist certain reducers, I would use Redux-Persist. If you want to something simple and built by yourself use the middleware option.

Comment: Thanks, i just want to save the token for requests and authentication, i think it is better to use cookie and local storage on browser, what do you think about it?

Comment: @SajadBeheshti Create a redux middleware that checks to see if the local storage / cookie is there before making a request and then restore it to the store or use it for the request.

Answer (score 0):

Redux store gets initial state upon app reload.
Try this: 
Make a dump component for local storage and use it anywhere you want.

**Constants.js**

```
export const USER_MODEL = {
set: ({ token, userInfo }) => {
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
localStorage.setItem('userInfo', userInfo);
},
remove: () => {
localStorage.removeItem('token');
localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
},
get: () => ({
token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo’),
})
};
```

**User.js**

```
import { USER_MODEL } from './Constants';
// just an example how you can set                    localStorage anywhere in your component 

USER_MODEL.set({
    token: “abc”,
    userInfo: {name: ‘foo’, city: ‘bar’},
  });

// get user model from localStorage
const token = localStorage.get().token;
const userInfo =   localStorage.get().userInfo;
```